# Incorrect syntax near COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, sum

```
SELECT D.Drank_Naam , D.Drank_Prijs, SUM(K.Aantal) AS Aantal COUNT(*) AS StudentDeelnemer,
            + FROM Kassa K,
            + JOIN DrankVoorraad AS D ON K.Drink_ID = D.ID,
            + JOIN StudentDeelnemer AS S on K.Student_Id = S.StudentNummer, 
            + group by D.Drank_Naam, D.Drank_Prijs;
```

I want to calculate the sum of drinks sold and the price, but i get an incorrect syntax near COUNT(*)

Comment: You forgot to add a comma before `COUNT(*)`

Comment: you have a missing comma` ,` in  `Aantal, COUNT(*)`

Comment: comma is missing.

Answer (score 2):

You have several misplaced commas in your query statement. here's the updated one:

```
SELECT D.Drank_Naam , D.Drank_Prijs, SUM(K.Aantal) AS Aantal, COUNT(*) AS StudentDeelnemer
   FROM Kassa K
 JOIN DrankVoorraad AS D ON K.Drink_ID = D.ID
 JOIN StudentDeelnemer AS S on K.Student_Id = S.StudentNummer
 group by D.Drank_Naam, D.Drank_Prijs;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT D.Drank_Naam , D.Drank_Prijs, SUM(K.Aantal) AS Aantal, COUNT(*) AS StudentDeelnemer,
            + FROM Kassa K,
            + JOIN DrankVoorraad AS D ON K.Drink_ID = D.ID,
            + JOIN StudentDeelnemer AS S on K.Student_Id = S.StudentNummer, 
            + group by D.Drank_Naam, D.Drank_Prijs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Youve missed a comma, try a little bit harder next time! you got it!

Answer (score 0):

a comma is missing here

```
SELECT D.Drank_Naam , D.Drank_Prijs, SUM(K.Aantal) AS Aantal, COUNT(*) AS StudentDeelnemer,
            + FROM Kassa K,
            + JOIN DrankVoorraad AS D ON K.Drink_ID = D.ID,
            + JOIN StudentDeelnemer AS S on K.Student_Id = S.StudentNummer, 
            + group by D.Drank_Naam, D.Drank_Prijs;
```

Answer (score 0):

pls be careful before asking a question.

look your script you ve missed a comma

```
SELECT D.Drank_Naam , D.Drank_Prijs, SUM(K.Aantal) AS Aantal, COUNT(*) AS StudentDeelnemer
   FROM Kassa K
 JOIN DrankVoorraad AS D ON K.Drink_ID = D.ID
 JOIN StudentDeelnemer AS S on K.Student_Id = S.StudentNummer
 group by D.Drank_Naam, D.Drank_Prijs;
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The moment you write query in SQL Server, its shows the warning line as i could see in my SQL Server.